# jQuery hide last 5 divs

Tags: jquery, html

How would I `show` the first 5 `div`s with the class `.stream`? Like which selector would I use? In jQuery.

Let's say I have this:

```
<div class='stream'>I'm testing this out
    <br><br>
    <div style='position:absolute;bottom:20px;right:20px;color:gray;'> - dumbsearch</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='stream'>jo
    <br><br>
    <div style='position:absolute;bottom:20px;right:20px;color:gray;'> - dumbsearch</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='stream'>what dat?
    <br><br>
    <div style='position:absolute;bottom:20px;right:20px;color:gray;'> - dumbsearch</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='stream'>hey
    <br><br>
    <div style='position:absolute;bottom:20px;right:20px;color:gray;'> - dumbsearch</div>
</div>
```

All and the `div`s with the class `stream` would be set to `display:none`, how would I display the first 5?

Thanks so much in advance! :)

Comment: Have you made any attempts on your own?  It is helpful to include the details of what you have tried to at least show some effort on your part.  Also, please format your html.  Proper line breaks and indentation make a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.stream:lt(5)').show();// MaGiC!!! yAy! :-D
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/gJFz9/

Comment: Shouldn't this be :lt(5), since he wants to display first 5?

Comment: You've been updating, I see. But unluckily for you, my page was cached and I see that you used to have :gt(), you big trickster.

Comment: +1 @neal for your answer, though I can't mark it as correct, being so graciously banned by you. :)

Comment: @user2041312 neal didn't ban you.  hes' not a moderator.

Comment: And I loved that cute story you made about me in the SO chat. :)) @neal

Comment: @neal These words were also just posted in SO chat: "If he'd just sign up as and not be a retard, showing us that it's him..." and "He's a kid ... doesn't think as far." I DO have other accounts on SO. This account is used for a sole purpose.